# Rxjava static generic utility method with transformer

Tags: android, rx-java

Recently I saw an `RxJava`[article](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) explaining `Transformers` and highlighting how they could be used to reuse `Schedulers`. I tried to use this and inside the same class, this method works fine:

```
<T>Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
        return new Observable.Transformer<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) {
                return observable
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to move this into a helper class with a static method so I can use it in my whole `Android`app. But when I try to use the method of this class

```
public class RxFunctions {

    public static <T>Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
        return new Observable.Transformer<T, T>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) {
                return observable
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

inside another class

```
public void requestLoginState() {
        restClient.requestLoginState()
                .compose(RxFunctions.applySchedulers())
                .subscribe(new TimberErrorSubscriber<LoginStateResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }
                    ...
```

it will no longer recognise my `Subscriber`, error: `Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous com.example.util.rx.TimberErrorSubscriber<com.example.network.retrofit.response.login.LoginStateResponse>)'`

I'm using `Java8`without `Retrolambda`.
Changing the compose line to

```
.compose(this.<LoginStateResponse> RxFunctions.applySchedulers())
```

results in an error for the LoginState type saying `Reference parameters are not allowed here`

I'm fairly new to `RxJava` and grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit: now Android does [support java 8](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)**

You say you are using Java8 on android, but android does not support Java8 without plugins like retrolambda, so I'll asume that you are actually compiling with Java6 (since Java7 only works for KitKat and above).

In that scenario, you might need to make explicit the parametric type of your `applySchedulers`. I believe you tried to do that when you wrote `this.<LoginStateResponse>`, but that would only work if your generic method is inside your current class.

In your case what you actually need is to specify the type on the static method call:

```
.compose(RxFunctions.<LoginStateResponse>applySchedulers())
```

Comment: You're right, my mistake with the Java version, I just looked at the project structure, forgetting that Android doesn't use Java8 yet.
I changed the call to your suggestion and it works fine, thank you very much

Comment: daamn i had to specify return type of Observable on each .Operator in order to subscribe that type on .subscribe()